# Getting error when try to add a file from library to main project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, using

I have created a library in c# and add this library to my project but I can't configure how to use the library file to the main project

I have tried the using line

```
using UserManagment.helper;
```

I am getting the error at UserManagment.helper while my original project is HPS.
the error is listed below :

> Error  2   The type or namespace name 'UserManagment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Ayesha\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\HPS\HPS\GUI\AdminProfile.cs   12  7   HPS

I expect that the UserManagment .helper will successfully be used by the project and declared in my required file

Comment: Have you added the .dll in reference?

Comment: i think no . How i can add .dll in reference?

Comment: @AyeshaIftikhar, In Solution Explorer -> Right click on Dependencies -> Add Reference..

Comment: okay! i will try this

Comment: @PWND which reference i have to add?

Comment: @AyeshaIftikhar, reference to your library. UserManagment as I think.

Comment: thank you i have solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you need to add the `.dll` as a reference to the project then only you will be able to access them in your project.

In Solution Explorer, right-click on the References or Dependencies node and choose Add Reference. You can also right-click on the project node and select Add > Reference.

[image: Example]

Use the browse button to locate the specific `.dll` and add the same to the project. Read more about this option [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019)